# Windows Server 2012 Disk Operations Freezing

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2

I've got 2x brand new Windows server 2012 R2 servers. Fresh install. All Windows updates applied. One on a brand-new physical server, and the other in our VMWare cluster.

When I try and perform a disk operation, such as moving or deleting 200GB of files, the operation runs for a few seconds and then pauses. The performance graph goes along at an acceptable rate and then drops off. I can't pause or stop the job.

I've been monitoring CPU, memory, network and disk activity. Everything seems very low.

VSS service is turned off.

Originally I thought this may be a hardware issue, however it's happening on both machines. We aren't having trouble with other servers in our VMWare cluster, either.

I was able to batch process about 1TB of files overnight (FFMpeg audio conversion). It went super well. When I tried to do a file operation in Windows Explorer at the same time as the job was running, my batch froze.

What would cause this?

After I've tried to delete the files and it freezes, I can't do any disk operations on that disk, such as creating a new folder. As this is a separate data disk, operations on the other disk (system disk) are still fine.

Comment: follow this and share the xperf trace: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60